# Changing font name in Table using php-odt

Tags: php, php-odt

I'm trying to change the font name of all text in my table using http://php-odt.sourceforge.net. Here is the code,

```
include 'phpodt-0.3/phpodt.php';

$odt = ODT::getInstance();

$table = new Table('table1');
$table->createColumns(3);
$table->addHeader(array('Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'));
$rows = array(array('1-1', '1-2', '1-3'), array('2-1', '2-2', '2-3'));
$table->addRows($rows);

$odt->output('test_table.odt');
```

I searched the [documentation of php-odt](http://php-odt.sourceforge.net/tutorials.php) haven't found anything.

Comment: You're likely not going to get much help with very specific scripts like `php-odt` here. You might have better luckcontacting the developer directly or using the [forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/php-odt/discussion/).

Comment: Actually, I think the lesson here is 'go to the source'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like this:

```
$tableStyle = new TableStyle('yourcsstablestyle'); //This appears to need to be a style class, where you can set font
$table = new Table('table1', $tableStyle);
```

The above is untested, but we can see in the PHP-ODT source code for `class.table.php`:

```
class Table {

    //Elide member variables

    /**
     *
     * @param DOMDocument $contentDoc The DOMDocument instance of content.xml
     * @param TableStyle $tableStyle A TableStyle object representing table style properties
     */
    public function __construct($tableName, $tableStyle = null) {
      ... //more code
```

You have to pass a `$tableStyle` value to get the table to style.

The `TableStyle` class's constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct($name) {
    parent::__construct($name);
    $this->styleElement->setAttribute('style:family', 'table');
    $this->tableProp = $this->contentDocument->createElement('style:table-properties');
    $this->styleElement->appendChild($this->tableProp);
}
```

Hence needing to pass the style class into the constructor of the `TableStyle`.

The documentation shows how to do [paragraph styling](http://php-odt.sourceforge.net/paragraphs.php) here, and the pattern seems the same.

Comment: 'Is not the same' is not a useful comment. What is not the same? What are you seeing, and what do you expect to see?

Comment: the pattern that you claim, is not the same

Comment: Why do you believe that to be true. If you've tried something, and seen output that is not what you expected, that is very useful diagnostic information for people helping you!

Comment: I poked around more in the code, and narrowed down the guess about what you have to do: I can't encourage you enough, though, to look at the code yourself!